# Array/Hash strange behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have performed the following test:

```
irb(main):023:0> a=[]
=> []

irb(main):024:0> b="1"
=> "1"

irb(main):025:0> a.push(b)
=> ["1"]

irb(main):026:0> a
=> ["1"]

irb(main):027:0> b="2"
=> "2"

irb(main):028:0> a
=> ["1"]
```

So far so good. Now, but as soon as I change b into a hash:

```
irb(main):012:0> a=[]
=> []
irb(main):013:0> b={}
=> {}
irb(main):014:0> b[:file]="one"
=> "one"
irb(main):015:0> a.push(b)
=> [{:file=>"one"}]
irb(main):016:0> a
=> [{:file=>"one"}]
irb(main):017:0> b[:file]="two"
=> "two"
irb(main):018:0> a
**=> [{:file=>"two"}]**
```

I didn't even push the b value into the a array. What happened here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is not a hash. It is a **reference** to a hash. And pushing a reference somewhere else won't make it point to a new instance.

**Copy your hashes explicitly** where you want to, using `b.dup`.

Sometimes even that might not be enough, as the same applies to values **inside** a hash: the new hash will have the same references inside, it's a so-called *"shallow copy"*.

(Here I was claiming that strings are immutable in Ruby, but @BroiSatse pointed out that it's not true, and he's right, follow the link in the comments.)

Regardless, the explaination is similar: **assignment of a new string** into a variable produces a **new reference** to a string (doesn't mutate existing one), **writing a new value into a hash doesn't** produce a new hash reference (mutates existing hash instead).

Comment: I know that it is a reference but why Hash becomes a reference and String does not

Comment: @D-side - Strings are so mutable!

Comment: @BroiSatse Um, yeah? Point me into the docs please, so I can be sure. Feel free to edit the answer as well.

Comment: @BroiSatse Nevermind, you are correct. Found evidence of otherwise. Deleting.

Comment: I can't delete an accepted answer, huh? Alright, I'll point that out shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how ruby variables and Arrays works. Variable holds a reference to the object, which means that if you do:

```
a = b = []
```

Both `a` and `b` are referencing exactly some object!

```
a << 1
b    #=> [1]
```

Array is nothing else but an object which holds many references at the same time. But again, they just reference objects, so if you do:

```
a = {}
b = [a]
```

Then `b[0]` and `a` variable are referencing to the same object.

```
a[:foo] = :bar
b    #=> [{:foo => :bar}]
```

Now the reason why it seemed to work differently in your first example is that assignment does not modify the object, but rather changes the reference itself.

```
a = []
b = '1'
a.push(b)
```

Now both `a[0]` and `b` are pointing to the very same object. However if you do:

```
b = '2'
```

You create a new string and changes **the reference** for variable `b`, but `a[0]` is still referencing the old string. However, if instead of changeng the reference you execute some modifying method:

```
b.replace('2')
```

You'll see it will give you:

```
a   #=> ['2']
```

Comment: So why this does not apply to the string?

Comment: It does, but you did not modify string, you've created a new string and assign it to the first variable. It does not modify the second variable, which still points to the previous string. Try using some string modifying methods, like `gsub!` or `replace` to see it applies there as well. I beleive it is explained in the answer, I'll try to reword it a little.

Comment: This one is good :)
irb(main):012:0> a=[]
=> []
irb(main):013:0> b=[]
=> []
irb(main):014:0> b.push("1")
=> ["1"]
irb(main):015:0> a.push(b)
=> [["1"]]
irb(main):016:0> b.push(a)
=> ["1", [[...]]]
irb(main):017:0> a
=> [["1", [...]]]
irb(main):018:0> b
=> ["1", [[...]]]

Comment: @meso_2600 - You can even do `a = []; a.push(a)`.